# Using Fragment in Drupal 7 Form Redirect

Tags: php, drupal, hook, drupal-7

I'm trying to redirect site admins away from content on update as it will never be directly viewed. Instead I am trying to link them to a specific section of the home page however while the redirect is occurring, the fragment option is being ignored.

```
function _content_redirect_to(&$form_state, $hash) {
    $destination = drupal_get_destination();
    if ($destination['destination'] != 'admin/content') {
        $form_state['redirect'] = array(
            '<front>', 
            array(
                'query' => array(),
                'fragment' => 'whatever',
                'absolute' => TRUE,
            ),
        );
    }
}

function _content_redirect_location($form, &$form_state) {
    _content_redirect_to($form_state, 'locations');
}

function content_redirect_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $link = l('test link', '<front>', array(
        'fragment' => 'locations'
    ));
    drupal_set_message($link); // Works just fine.
    switch ($form_id) {
        case 'location_node_form':
            $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = '_content_redirect_location';
            break;
    }
}
```

The same thing happens when I call drupal_goto directly on update.

```
function content_redirect_node_update($node) {
    if ($node->type == 'location') {
        drupal_goto(
            '<front>', array(
                'fragment' => 'locations'
            )
        );
    }
}
```

I haven't been able to find information on this else where.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is:

```
$form_state['redirect'] = array('<front>', array('fragment' => 'location'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that's not a perfect solution, but try this:

```
$form['#action'] = url($_GET['q'], array('query' => array('destination' => 'DESIRED_LOCATION')));
```